# Ubuntu on my MacBook Pro Retina 2015

Tags: macosx

I was trying to dual boot linux with mac os x. Everything was fine, until i tried to switch from ubuntu back to os x. After typing my password, this happened. (I couldn't submit the image, but it is a blackscreen with a white logo indicating that it is prohibited. Imagine the "no parking allowed" sign without the letter E)

So I was thinking of overwriting ubuntu and make it my only os, and then try to reinstall os x. Any tips or can someone help me solve this? Or should I just stick with ubuntu? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up the partition that MacOS is installed i believe, follow [this guide](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/18/clean-install-os-x-yosemite/) in order to reinstall MacOS. I assume you don't have any important data on your pc since it's a brand new one. If you wanna access your files and copy them into a external drive or something

- Boot up to LiveCD of ubuntu
- Follow [this answer from superuser](https://superuser.com/a/365270) to mount your MacOS Hdd
- I believe you would be able to rescue your data, i have no access to a mac however mounting the partition worked for me in a situation with Windows.